# Different Documents in Different Views in the Same Library

Tags: document, view, library

I'm fairly new to Sharepoint, and am developing an internal site for my department. I'm hoping to use one Library for a general theme of documents around past performance, for example. I have figured out how to create a particular view for these documents and added columns to sort by assigned meta data. I then created a different view for capacity statements, which are related but not the same. However, all of the documents that I uploaded for the first view (Past Performance) are now showing up in both views. Can I restrict which documents appear in which views, or will I need to create a separate library?

Answer (score 0):

You can use filters to restrict documents in each view. Suppose you add a choice column named "Document Type" and keep the choice values as "Performance Documents" and "Capacity Statements". When a document is added to the library either of these values can be selected. Now, you need to create two views and specify the filter on "Document Type"